# Styling checkboxes in Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkbox

When customising the look of a checkbox using CSS, to be able to work the magic we first need to link an element (eg. label) to the checkbox.

```
<label for="toggle-1">Do Something</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
```

However I am using Contact form 7 (wordpress plugin) and I cannot find where to add the id within the checkbox. If you specify an id in CF7 it adds it to the containing div (.wpcf7-form-control), and not the checkbox itself.

Therefore I can't get it working.

Am I missing something? is there another way to link the label and the checkbox?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The format used by *Contact Form 7* is a little different from your HTML, but there are some targeting options that should be sufficient to grab any element you need.

When creating your form, you'll generate a checkbox shortcode that looks something like this.

`[checkbox my-checkbox id:my-checkboxes use_label_element "foo" "bar"]`

This code will generate:

- A set of two checkboxes
- Each of the two is wrapped in a `<label>` element (the text itself is in a `<span>`)
- A parent element with the id="my-checkboxes"`

So the output markup will look something like this (along with some wpcf7 and Wordpress classes).

```
<span id="my-checkboxes">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="foo" /><span>foo</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="bar" /><span>bar</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Since you have an ID on the parent element, you can target this specific part of the form and elements within it using selectors in CSS or JQuery.

For example `#mycheckboxes > label > input` and `#mycheckboxes > label > input + span`.

For better targeting options, you can also create one checkbox per shortcode and assign an ID to each `<span>` checkbox container.

```
[checkbox my-checkbox id:a-checkbox use_label_element "foo"]
[checkbox my-checkbox2 id:another-checkbox use_label_element "bar"]
```

Since you're ultimate goal is to feed the information into Contact Form 7 (presumably to email it somewhere), it doesn't matter if you create each checkbox with a separate shortcode.